# How to specify the schema for the Payara EJB__TIMER__TBL

Tags: java, glassfish, payara

Currently there seems to be no option to set the schema in which Payara creates the EJB__TIMER_TBL table.

Our project is a legacy Java EE application, currently being migrated from Glassfish 3 to Payara 4.1.2.182.1.
The application uses multiple data sources and several (persistent) timers, therefore Payara creates the EJB__TIMER__TBL in the specified timer-datasource: config.server-config.ejb-container.ejb-timer-service.timer-datasource, which is fine.
`<ejb-timer-service timer-datasource="jdbc/abc"></ejb-timer-service>`

The timer data source is a PostgreSQL 9.6 database and the EJB__TIMER__TBL table gets created in the 'public' schema, **which is not OK**.
We tried to create the EJB__TIMER__TBL explicitly in the desired schema (e.g. appschema). It did not help, the table is still created (also) in schema 'public' (and we suppose the application uses that table).
The application uses Hibernate (4.3.11.Final) as persistence provider / entity manager, and the schema to be used is specified with the  persistence-unit property in persistence.xml.

Note: GMS is enabled for the application.

Anyone knows how the schema can be specified for Payara where to create the EJB__TIMER__TBL table?
If creation of the EJB__TIMER__TBL table can be avoided (and persistent timer states can be stored differently), then please also let me know.

Comment: You're using a version of Payara Server, which is only available for support customers. You'd better contact either Payara Support or your client. If they provided you with the binaries they most probably have a support contract.

Comment: Hello Ondrej, Thanks for the hint!
I actually created a Payara issue for this, which was tagged as enhancement: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/3078
I'll also check with the client about support options.
Btw how do you know that this version is only available for support customers? Is it the **.1** at the end of the version (4.1.2.182.1)?

Comment: The latest public version of Payara 4 is 4.1.2.181 released in February. Since then, only Payara 5 versions are released publicly, e.g 5.182 is public. The .1 versions have always been only for customers for both Payara 4 and 5. All sources are public but official binaries are available publicly and for free only for quarterly releases of Payara 5. Binaries for patch releases of Payara 5 and all releases of Payara 4 since 4.1.2.182 are only for customers with support contract.